# Encode JSON object to base 64

Tags: javascript, json, base64

I have a following JSON object :

```
{
"caseId": "42608237",
"caseNo": "5001g000000fghqAAA",
"descriptiveName": "test",
"addNote": "test"
}
```

Resulting encoded base 64 string : 
DQp7DQogICJjYXNlSWQiOiAiNDI2MDgyMzciLA0KICAiY2FzZU5vIjogIjUwMDFnMDAwMDAwZmdocUFBQSIsDQogICJkZXNjcmlwdGl2ZU5hbWUiOiAidGVzdCIsDQogICJhZGROb3RlIjogInRlc3QiDQp9

**I want to encode the above object to base 64.** 
I tried to convert the object to string first and then use btoa function on the string to encode it. Is it the right approach?

Comment: why do you need to encode that object to babssae 64? what is the reason ?

Comment: Yeah! You have answered your question, that is how it is done.

Comment: your approach is good

Comment: @Vishantdhandha : I need to encode and send it as a part of header

Comment: @HemanthRaj : Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @AmitWagner : Thanks for the clarification :)